# Cognos 10.1 Charts with multiple Axis, multiple series with and multiple axis lining up

Tags: charts, cognos-10

Here is my report structure:

- MM-YY as my Category (X Axis)
- Referral Method 1, Referral Method 2 and Referral Method 3 as my Primary y axis
- Referral Method 1%, Referral Method 2%, and Referral Method 3% as my secondary y axis.

I have been able to create a chart that contains multiple axis. The only issue is if my primary Y axis is bar, and my secondary y axis is a line The values from the secondary axis do not match up to the primary y axis series. All of the values from the secondary axis stick together in the middle of the category.

My Primary Axis series does not line up with my secondary axis series. (there are 3 items in each series)

Look at the first image below. The secondary values all clump together in the middle of Jan-15. I want them to all separate within Jan-15 like the bars do. Could anyone help me accomplish this?
Thank you

Edit: image links below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As long as you're not able to post images you need to place them on a public server and include the link. Once you got a little reputation you can also post images directly.

Comment: Added links to images.Thanks